# CSS - positioning a background image on a fluid layout

Tags: background-image, fluid, css

so the layout is like this:

```
<div style="width: 100%;" class="container">

  <div class="col1" style="width:30%;float:left;">  
   column 1
  </div>

  <div class="col2" style="width:70%;float:left">  
   column 2
  </div>

</div>
```

I want to make `div.col1` a different color, so for this I'm using a vertically repeating background image on `div.container`. The problem is that this container is fluid and I don't know how to position the image.

I tried something like this, but it doesn't work when you resize the browser window:

```
.container{background: transparent url(images/bg.png) repeat-y -70% top;
```

Are there any ways to do this?

Comment: Why can't you just put the background on column 1 if that's where you want it anyway?

Comment: because column 2 can have a higher height and then the background from col 1 doesn't stretch to the entire page height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know all your requirements, but it will work better if you can set the `background-color` of `.container` to what you want your left column to be, and then use the repeated image to fill the right column. The reason being that the background positioning cannot be done from the right, only the left. So something like:

```
.container{background: #ffffff url(images/bg.png) repeat-y 30% top}
```

Where the `#ffffff` represents the left column color, and the `bg.png` the right column. If you really need the left to be the png, then you will probably need a second wrapper around the floated divs. Something like:

```
<div style="width: 100%;" class="container">
<div class="inner">
   <div class="col1" style="width:30%;float:left;">  
     column 1
   </div>

   <div class="col2" style="width:70%;float:left">  
     column 2
   </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Set the `inner` wrapper (this could just be a solid color rather than a repeated image):

```
.inner{background: url(images/bgright.png) repeat-y 30% top}
```

And your container:

```
.container{background: url(images/bgleft.png) repeat-y left top}
```

The 30% 'gap' of the `inner` will allow the left 30% column's background to show through from the `container`.